# Update serializer data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to add a dictionary to my serialized data but I'm getting an error `dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required`

This is what I have tried:

```
def get_data(self, request):

    created_by = User_Detail.objects.get(auth_token__isnull=False)
    newdict = {'created_by': created_by.id}
    details = ExSerializer(Tower.objects.all(), many=True).data
    newdict.update(details)
    return Response({"expenses": newdict})
```

I tried the above **code** but it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you share the code for User_Detail, ExSerializer and Tower?

Comment: Its way to long. I can share serializer data, if it works ?

Comment: yes, that will be helpful for identifying the issue

Comment: Hey @cwlau I have updated with serializer.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is you are trying to update a dictionary with a list.

The minimal code to simulate this issue:

```py
d = {1: "one", 2: "three"}
d.update([(1,)])
```

will gives an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
    d.update([(1,)])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

For your case, you are updating `newdict` with a list coming from `ExSerializer` (`Tower.objects.all()` with `many=True`).

To solve this, you will need to adjust your code to extract only one record from `Tower`, or make a list of results that combine each user to one `Tower` record, depends on your exact use case.

-- EDIT --

If you want all records of `Tower` in one request, you will need to apply multiple serializers.

The code will be similar to this (not tested):

```py
def get_data(self, request):
    created_by = User_Detail.objects.get(auth_token__isnull=False)
    return Response({"expenses": UserDetailSerializer({"created_by": created_by}).data})


class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = serializers.IntegerField()
    details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User_Detail
        fields = ('created_by', 'details')

    def get_details(self, obj):
        return ExSerializer(Tower.objects.all(), many=True).data
```

Comment: but I want all the records @cwlau